# Issue with passing data to an observable in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm setting up a template system in my knockout project and the goal is to be able to call the function loadTemplate("templateName") at any time to load a new template into a view.

I have a version of it working in which I can call `loadHomeTemplate()` or `loadSearchTemplate()` and it'll work.

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sDQW3/1/).

But now I'm trying to modify it so that I can call `loadTemplate("Home")` or `loadTemplate("Search")`.

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qGbTU/1/).

For some reason the 2nd version breaks on `this.name = ko.observable(name);`. this.name is undefined - I've added console logs to see the error. I don't get it. It seems like I'm passing the same thing to buildTemplate's 'name' parameter in both cases. No?

*A couple notes:* I'm binding to the 'template-content' element like that because I'm running multiple view models. And I'm declaring `loadTemplate` or `loadHomeTemplate` as globals because I need to be able to run the methods any time. There's probably a better way to do it, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that `buildTemplate` must be used with `new` since it initializes itself as holder of selected template. This fix resolves improper access to `name`.

```
self.currentTemplate(new buildTemplate(name, templateData));
```

In my fork I've also created `templateFactory` object that holds inside constructors for all specific templates. It makes searching of proper constructor easy and confident.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvYY4/1/

Comment: Right. I can't believe I was missing the 'new' declaration. I like the templateFactory idea too. Good move! Thank you.